# SQL/EF Applying defaultvalue to entries that cannot be null any longer

Tags: sql, entity-framework

We added a new column in a migration, and then need to modify it to no longer be nullable. The entries are null, however.

Is there a way to apply default value as part of the migration, to entries where the value is null?

Or is the best solution simply to run a stored procedure, or otherwise manually edit the fields to be something valid?

ps. Did the later, because i'm a student, needed it working now, and it was just 8 entries, but i'm still curious.

Comment: One simple way is to add some manual SQL as part of your migration, for example: `Sql("UPDATE MyTable SET SomeColumn = 0");`

Answer (score 0):

DavidG's response is pretty much what I did in a testbed, and it works perfectly well.